# Algorithms for two and three dimensional Knapsack

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-complete, computational-geometry, knapsack-problems

I know that the 2D and 3D Knapsack problems are NPC, but is there any way to solve them in reasonable time if the instances are not very complicated? Would dynamic programming work?

By 2D (3D) Knapsack I mean I have a square (cube) and a I have list of objects, all data are in centimeters and are at most 20m.

Comment: What forms do your objects have? How big is the surrounding area; has it bounded size?

Comment: Are you searching for an exact solver or are heuristics sufficient?

Comment: The sizes are bounded by 20m. For 2D, the shapes are made of lines and arcs, but even the rectangular case would be helpful. For 3D it is complicated, but the rectangular cubes case will be helpful. I also have a restriction in the 3D case that some objects can not be put over others (if it is too heavy it will crush the one below it).

Comment: I want to fit at many objects as possible. Approximation is fine if there is not a good exact algorithm.

Comment: Let me know if the algorithm will also work if the data are in mm in place of cm.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What are "sizes", and what is $m$?  What _precisely_ is your input, what _precisely_ are your constraints, and what _precisely_ are you trying to optimize?

Comment: Also, what have you already tried?

Comment: @JeffE, it seems to me that in the 2D case the inputs are the dimensions of the objects plus the dimensions of the knapsack, and goal is to maximize the number of objects in the knapsack (minimizing the total free space left might be more reasonable though). In the 3D case, the objects have weight and heavier objects cannot be place over lighter objects.

Comment: The problem you're talking about isn't generally referred to as a knapsack problem; it usually goes by the name _bin-packing problem_, and you should be able to find a lot more information about it under that name.

Comment: What does "NPC" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Knapsack can be [solved by dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_Programming_Algorithm) in *[pseudo-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time)* time $O(nW)$ with $n$ the number of objects and $W$ the size of the knapsack. So, as long as your container is small (numerically), you can solve the problem efficiently. Note that you can adjust $W$ by changing resolution; no need to measure a shipping container to the µm, but meters are probably to coarse (depending on your objects).

Knapsack can also be [approximated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Approximation_Algorithms) arbitrarily well in polynomial time (see [polynomial-time approximation schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme)).

However, Knapsack only considers fitting numbers into another number; it does not care about geometrics. If you need to "puzzle", you need another problem; considering Tetris, this is probably [much harder than Knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris#Computational_complexity).

Answer (score 0):

GREEDY will always find a reasonable solution, but not necessarily the optimal one. Simply put the largest object which will fit each time in the knapsack. Stop when no more objects will fit.

Comment: No, that is not true. Note that in the Knapsack problem, objects have values, too. Filling greedily by size can yield an arbitrarily bad solution.

Comment: @Raphael: Well, not arbitrarily bad, but I wouldn't consider the greedy solution a **reasonable** solution. The greedy approach gets worse for the higher dimensional analogues.

Comment: @A.Schulz Actually yes arbitrarily bad! The greedy heuristic for knapsack, using either size or bang-for-buck can easily be shown to not have any finite approximation guarantee to OPT.

Comment: People... please stop saying "Well, I don't know about that! But..." before doing your *%#$(* homework on it!